# Power App Reset Button - Resets to Default when I want a blank

Tags: powerbi, powerapps, powerapps-formula

[image]

New to Power Apps . I have a power app linked to a Power BI Record . In this scenario where it brings a rental value from the Power BI Record , initially it should take the value for the customer from the Power BI record . When an user clicks on the RESET button it should blank the text box, but it resets it to the default which is the Power BI Record value . Is there a way to get a value when the form comes up and then when the RESET button is pressed it wipes out the text box instead of going to what is in the DEFAULT property for the text box/ data card in the power app ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please have a look here http://powerappsguide.com/blog/post/controls-how-to-reset-or-clear-data-entry-controls-and-form-values, this very well explains resetting the values.